# Warping though SVG

Tags: svg

Is it possible to apply a warp transformation on an image in a SVG ?
The goal if to "bend" an image, as if it was stuck on a cylinder, therefore going from this :

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No.  Not easily.

SVG only supports [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

If your SVG was pure vectors, you could achieve the affect by manipulating the path points using your own non-affine transformation code.  But that wouldn't work for bitmap images.

However you can warp bitmaps with a Canvas element.  Or perhaps with WebGL.